# How do I make a symlink to every directory in the current directory that has the same name but has underscores replaced by dashes?

Tags: bash, symlink

For instance, I suppose I have a directory that contains the following folders

```
foo_bar
baz
```

What I would like to have is a bash command that will make a symlink `foo-bar` to `foo_bar` so it would look like this:

```
foo-bar
foo_bar
baz
```

I'm pretty sure I can write a Python script to do this, but I'm curious if there's a way to do this with bash.  Here's where I'm stuck:

```
ls -1 | grep _ | xargs -I {} ln -s {} `{} | sed 's/_/-/'`
```

What I'm trying to do is run the command `ln -s` with the first argument being the directory name and the second argument being that name passed through `sed s/_/-/`.  Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash can substitute in strings!

```
for path in *_*; do [ -d "$path" ] && ln -s "$path" "${path//_/-}"; done
```

If you want to be more selective about what to apply it to, you could do something similar:

```
find . -type d [other tests...] | while read path; do [ -d "$path" ] && ln -s "$path" "${path//_/-}"; done
```

Or your `ls ... | grep ...` instead of the `find`, of course.

A helpful reference for string manipulation, including that substitution: [Manipulating Strings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

Comment: Wow; I didn't know this.  And I was calling sed all the time.  =]

Comment: @strager: sed is obviously much more powerful. This is just literal string substitution, not regex. But when that's what you need, it's nice to avoid spawning the extra process!

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), but here's how you could use it with `sed` and 'xargs` to do what you want (it won't work if there are spaces in the filenames):

```
ls *_* | sed 'h;s/_/-/g;x;G;s/\n/ /' | xargs ln -s
```

However, I would do it the way **Jefromi** showed.